# Как заменить своим текстом ошибку php

Tags: php, mysql

Если выдает любую ошибку при отправке формы php mysql что бы заменяло на текст "что-то пошло не так" как такое устроить?

Comment: Жи и ши  пиши через И! А вопрос очень размытый, чтобы дать ответ.

Comment: удалите вопрос и почитайте про if/else/try/catch

Comment: можете не удалять, но уточните вопрос – какие есть сейчас ошибки.  Ещё посмотрите про [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) – можете назначить свою функцию обрабатывать любые ошибки php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обработка ошибок расширений для работы с MySQL сильно зависит от того, какое расширение вы используете. В случае устаревшего расширения mysql необходимо проверять дескриптор запроса, после вызова каждой функции `mysql_query()`

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wrong_table';
$res = mysql_query($query);
if($res) exit('Ошибка извлечения данных из таблицы');
```

Если запросов в скрипте много, можно вместо остановки скрипта генерировать исключение, которое перехватывать в конце скрипта

```
try
{
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM wrong_table';
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if($res) throw new Exception('Ошибка извлечения данных из таблицы');
  ...
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo 'Произошла исключительная ситуация: '.$e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Однако, расширение mysql является устаревшим и уже исключено из PHP 7. Вместо него используется либо mysqli, либо PDO.

Расширение PDO предоставляет несколько режимов обработки ошибок. По умолчанию используется "тихий" режим, работу которого мы только что наблюдали. Извлечь сообщение об ошибке в нем можно, только явно обратившись к методу `errorInfo()`.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wrong_table';
$res = $pdo->query($query);
if($res) {
  print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
  exit('Ошибка извлечения данных из таблицы');
}
```

Однако можно переключить режим обработки ошибок при помощи дополнительных параметров конструктора PDO.

- `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` — "тихий режим". Сообщения об ошибках обработки запросов можно извлечь при помощи метода `errorInfo()`. Сигналом об возникновении ошибок служат значения false, возвращаемые методами обработки запросов.
- `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` — режим генерации предупреждений. В случае возникновения ошибок обработки SQL-запроса PDO выдает предупреждение PHP.
- `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` — режим генерации исключений. В случае возникновения ошибок в SQL-запросах PDO генерирует исключение `PDOException`.

Ниже приводится пример установки соединения с сервером MySQL и перевод PDO в режим генерации исключений

```
try {
  $pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
                  'root',
                  '',
                  [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
}
```

После этого, любая ошибка со стороны сервера будет вызывать генерацию исключения типа `PDOExeption`, которое можно перехватить в блоке `catch`

```
try {
  ...
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM wrong_table';
  $res = $pdo->query($query);
  ...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
exit('что-то пошло не так');
```

Comment: @strangeqargo, как грубо, однако.

Comment: :3 не так уж грубо, учитывая гонку ответов, вместо того чтобы или улучшить ответ, или удалить его.

Comment: Тема не раскрыта

Answer (score -1):

Возможно так:

```
try{
    something
} catch(exception) {
   die('Something wrong ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: mysqli, mysql, pdo::query  не бросают эксепшенов, чтоб вы знали. кроме того, у вас ошибка в коде.

Comment: да стрэнжекварго прав сдесь надо проверять ошибки самому и кидать экскепшион. плюс у вас ошибка в коде. пдо может кидать если установить самому чтобы кидало